# Use of the term 'dimension' in word-embeddings or various other tensors in AI

Tags: neural-networks, high-dimensional, word-embeddings

I've noticed that AI community refers to various tensors as 512-d, meaning 512 dimensional tensor, where the term 'dimension' seems to mean 512 different float values in the representation for a single datapoint. e.g. in 512-d word-embeddings means 512 length vector of floats used to represent 1 english-word e.g. https://medium.com/@jonathan_hui/nlp-word-embedding-glove-5e7f523999f6

But it isn't 512 different dimensions, it's only 1 dimensional vector? Why is the term `dimension` used in such a different manner than usual?

When we use the term `conv1d` or `conv2d` which are convolutions over 1-dimension and 2-dimensions, a dimension is used in the typical way it's used in math/sciences but here a 1-d vector is said to be a 512-d vector, or am I missing something?

Why is this overloaded use of the term `dimension`? What context determines what `dimension` means in machine-learning as the term seems overloaded?

Comment: It comes down to what you might mean by "typical way it's used in math," because mathematicians recognize that one and the same object can be viewed in relation to many different vector spaces. For instance, a humble $2\times 2$ matrix may represent a linear map from a 2D space to another 2D space; or be considered just a special way to write a 4-vector; or to be a tensor of type $(2,0)$ (a 4D space); or, if the matrix is symmetric, it might be considered an element of the 3D space of symmetric tensors; and so on.  Which of these can be considered "typical"??

Comment: thanks. why is the question downvoted?

Comment: @sycorax If any issue with the post I can edit, but why is the post downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dimension of word embeddings is the [dimension of the vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_(vector_space)) they live in, not the dimension of the tensor which is 1. Therefore, it *is* common in mathematical jargon (just an overloaded term).

I don't think you will have much trouble to disambiguate based on the context. There are clues everywhere. For matrices, for example, it is frequent to read "A matrix of dimension $n \times n$" which makes it pretty unambiguous.